# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in the for loop

Tags: php, loops

I just have a simple for loop, however I keep getting this error and I cannot figure out what is wrong with the loop. I have researched the error and it is most likely a missing semi-colon or parentheses etc. Something simple...

```
for ($t=1; $t<=16; ++$t)
{
    $game$t = $_POST["game$t"];
}
```

Comment: you are trying to name a variable dynamically based on the value of $t?  it is possible, but not like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you did not look up the manual page for the feature that you're trying to use. Something simple, indeed.

I think you're [looking for](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) `${game.$t}` (not `$game$t`) in order to create a "family of variables" whose names all share a common prefix:

```
for ($t=1; $t<=16; ++$t) {
    ${game.$t} = $_POST["game$t"];
}
```

But I'd really suggest that you use an array instead:

```
$games = Array();
for ($t=1; $t<=16; ++$t) {
    $games[$t] = $_POST["game$t"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$game$t` is not a valid variable name.

You can use something like `$game{$t}` instead

Comment: "Something like" not that. You need concatenation to make that work. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write `$game$t`. If you really need variable variable names (I advise against it, it's not the best practice), you have to write it like this:

```
$name = "game$t";
$$name = $_POST["game$t"];
```